# GLSL 4.00 is not supported

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am working with JOGL. I have: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 35)
I just update mesa to version 17.0. My Intel drive is the i915 which seems to be the right one based on what I have read.

I still cant get a shader to compile when indicating #version 430 I'm not interested in using the embeded versions of GLSL "ES".

output of glxinfo | grep "opengl":

```
    OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 405 (Braswell) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.1.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.1.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 17.1.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

What can I do to use version 430? I'm pretty sure my graphics card will support it.

```
    lspci -nn |egrep "VGA|Display"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22b1] (rev 35)
```

shader:

```
#version 400 core

layout (location=0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 mv_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = proj_matrix * mv_matrix * vec4(position,1.0);
}
```

createshader():

```
GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        int[] vertCompiled = new int[1];
        int[] fragCompiled = new int[1];
        int[] linked = new int[1];

        String[] vshaderSource;
        String[] fshaderSource;
        vshaderSource = readShaderSource("resources/vert.shader");
        fshaderSource = readShaderSource("resources/frag.shader");

        int vShader = gl.glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        gl.glShaderSource(vShader,vshaderSource.length,vshaderSource, null, 0);
        gl.glCompileShader(vShader);
```

full:

```
public class FirstApp extends JFrame implements GLEventListener {
    private int vao[] = new int[1];
    private int vbo[] = new int[2];
    private int rendering_program;
    private GLCanvas myCanvas;
    private float cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ;
    private float cubeLocX, cubeLocY, cubeLocZ;
    private GLSLUtils util = new GLSLUtils();
    private Matrix3D pMat;


    public FirstApp(){
        setSize(600,600);
        setLocation(200,200);
        myCanvas = new GLCanvas();
        myCanvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        this.add(myCanvas);
        setVisible(true);
//        FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(myCanvas, 50);
//        animator.start();
    }

    public void init(GLAutoDrawable draw){ 
        GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        rendering_program = createShaderProgram();
        setupVertices();
        cameraX = 0.0f; cameraY = 0.0f; cameraZ = 8.0f;
        cubeLocX = 0.0f; cubeLocY = -2.0f; cubeLocZ = 0.0f;


    }

    private void setupVertices(){
        GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        float[] vertex_positions = {
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f
        };

        gl.glGenVertexArrays(vao.length, vao, 0);
        gl.glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
        gl.glGenBuffers(vbo.length, vbo, 0);

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
        FloatBuffer vertBuf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vertex_positions);
        gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuf.limit() * 4, vertBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    private Matrix3D perspective(float fovy, float aspect, float n, float f){
        float q = 1.0f / ((float) Math.tan(Math.toRadians(0.5f * fovy)));
        float A = q / aspect;
        float B = (n + f) / (n-f);
        float C = (2.0f * n * f) / (n-f);
        Matrix3D r = new Matrix3D();
        r.setElementAt(0,0,A);
        r.setElementAt(1,1,q);
        r.setElementAt(0,0,B);
        r.setElementAt(3,2,-1.0f);
        r.setElementAt(2,3,C);
        r.setElementAt(3,3,0.0f);
        return r;
    }

    private int createShaderProgram(){
        //compiles and links fragment shader and vertex shader

        GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        int[] vertCompiled = new int[1];
        int[] fragCompiled = new int[1];
        int[] linked = new int[1];

        String[] vshaderSource;
        String[] fshaderSource;
        vshaderSource = readShaderSource("resources/vert.shader");
        fshaderSource = readShaderSource("resources/frag.shader");

        int vShader = gl.glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        gl.glShaderSource(vShader,vshaderSource.length,vshaderSource, null, 0);
        gl.glCompileShader(vShader);
        checkOpenGLError();
        gl.glGetShaderiv(vShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, vertCompiled, 0);
        if(vertCompiled[0] == 1){
            System.out.println("comilation is a success");
        } else {
            System.out.println("compilation failed...");
            printShaderLog(vShader);
        }


        int fShader = gl.glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        gl.glShaderSource(fShader, fshaderSource.length, fshaderSource,null, 0);
        gl.glCompileShader(fShader);
        checkOpenGLError();
        gl.glGetShaderiv(fShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, fragCompiled, 0);
        if(fragCompiled[0] == 1){
            System.out.println("fragment comilation is a success");
        } else {
            System.out.println("fragment compilation failed...");
            printShaderLog(fShader);
        }

        if((vertCompiled[0] != 1) || (fragCompiled[0] != 1)){
            System.out.println("\nCompilation error; return-flags: ");
            System.out.println("vercompiled = "+ vertCompiled[0] + " frag compiled = " +fragCompiled[0]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Succesful compilation");
        }


        int vfprogram = gl.glCreateProgram();
        gl.glAttachShader(vfprogram, vShader);
        gl.glAttachShader(vfprogram, fShader);
        gl.glBindAttribLocation(vfprogram,0,"position");
        gl.glLinkProgram(vfprogram);

        checkOpenGLError();
        gl.glGetProgramiv(vfprogram, GL_LINK_STATUS, linked, 0);
        if(linked[0] == 1){
            System.out.println("linking is a success");
        } else {
            System.out.println("link failed...");
            printProgramLog(vfprogram);
        }

        gl.glDeleteShader(vShader);
        gl.glDeleteShader(fShader);
        return vfprogram;

    }

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable){
        GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();

        gl.glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glUseProgram(rendering_program);
        int mv_loc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(rendering_program,"mv_matrix");
        int proj_loc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(rendering_program, "proj_matrix");
        float aspect = (float) myCanvas.getWidth() / (float) myCanvas.getHeight();
        Matrix3D pMat = perspective(60.0f, aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
        Matrix3D vMat = new Matrix3D();
        vMat.translate(-cameraX, -cameraY, -cameraZ);

        Matrix3D mMat = new Matrix3D();
        mMat.translate(cubeLocX, cubeLocY, cubeLocZ);

        Matrix3D mvMat = new Matrix3D();
        mvMat.concatenate(vMat);
        mvMat.concatenate(mMat);

        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(mv_loc, 1, false, mvMat.getFloatValues(), 0);
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc, 1, false, pMat.getFloatValues(), 0);

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT, false, 0,0);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

        gl.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

    }

    private void printShaderLog(int shader){
        GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        int[] len = new int[1];
        int[] chWritten = new int[1];
        byte[] log = null;

        gl.glGetShaderiv(shader,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,len,0);
        if(len[0] > 0){
            log = new byte[len[0]];
            gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader,len[0], chWritten, 0, log, 0);
            System.out.println("Shader info log: ");
            for( int i =0; i < log.length; i++){
                System.out.print((char) log[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    void printProgramLog(int prog){
        GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        int[] len = new int[1];
        int[] chWritten = new int[1];
        byte[] log = null;

        gl.glGetProgramiv(prog,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,len,0);
        if(len[0] > 0){
            log = new byte[len[0]];
            gl.glGetProgramInfoLog(prog,len[0], chWritten, 0, log, 0);
            System.out.println("Program info log: ");
            for( int i =0; i < log.length; i++){
                System.out.print((char) log[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    boolean checkOpenGLError(){
        GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        boolean foundError = false;
        GLU glu = new GLU();
        int glErr = gl.glGetError();

        while(glErr != GL_NO_ERROR){
            System.err.println("glError: "+glu.gluErrorString(glErr));
            foundError = true;
            glErr = gl.glGetError();
        }

        return foundError;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FirstApp();
    }

    public String[] readShaderSource(String path) {
        //reads in shader programs
       ArrayList<String> builder = new ArrayList();

        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.add(line+"\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load a shader file!"
                                       + System.lineSeparator() + ex.getMessage());
        }
        CharSequence source = builder.toString();

        return builder.toArray(new String[1]);
    }

    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable draw, int x, int y, int width, int height){ }
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable draw){ }

}
```

Comment: Show your shader and how you try to compile it. Please also show how you create your context.

Comment: I read that you have to specify that you want opengl 4 when creating the context. Is that true? How do you do that ?

Comment: How do you create your context now? And yes, you have to tell OpenGL that you want a specific version and a core profile.

Comment: GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL(); Is'nt this the context creation?

Comment: Any idea BDL? I've been trying to figure this out all day please help.

Comment: Where was GLContext created?  getCurrentGL just returns it.

Comment: hm maybe that would clear somethings up. I'm learning this from a book. Nothing in the example code shows anything like createNewContext().

Comment: I thought what I just posted was somekind of factory for the context. Any suggestions on reading material ?

Comment: I just posted the full source. Anything clicking ?

Comment: What's the error from the shader?  Show the fragment shader.

Comment: I don't see something like  `GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL4);`

Comment: @Robinson the shader is there lol

Comment: @madmax I see a vertex shader.  I don't see a fragment shader.

Comment: I followed the "duplicate" post. The problem for me is that glxinfo says I have version 4.5 but when I print out the version from java it still says

Comment: GL VER: 3.0 Mesa 17.1.2shader vers: 1.30

Comment: Can someone tell me what the difference between 'core profile version string and gl version' ? Like what's shown above ?

Comment: @Scott Gordon  can you help me out ?

Comment: The second answer in the duplicate post is the fix here. Thanks Guys!